# Custom Links with Messenger Bot via Microsoft Botframework

Tags: node.js, botframework, facebook-messenger-bot

Clicking https://www.messenger.com/t/xxxxxxxx will take you to a bot and continue the conversation, if there was no conversation it'll begin it's 'firstRun' sequence.

Is it possible to create links that will execute a specific dialog and pass in data? It should ignore previous dialog state/stack and start a new stack with the specified data as argument to that dialog.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. The url is used to identify the user/bot in messenger. The bot doesn't see the url so it can't read from it.

I would suggest taking a different approach. You could let the user pass in the code instead of adding it to the url.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new functionality in Messenger platform that allows  you to send specific messages to a bot: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/referral-params
I haven't tested it yet, but it may help you.